# Matlab: select subarrays from indexes matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

I have a logical array `B` and a matrix `A` of size `n`x`2` containing `n` couples of start/stop indexes

```
A= [start1, stop1; start2, stop2; start3, stop3];
```

How can I select the subarrays of array `B` based on start/stop couples contained in array `A`?

I'm doing it by:

```
for i=1:1:size(A,1)     
    B(A(i,1):A(i,2)) = true;    
end
```

Is there any way of doing it in a more elegant way without using the for cycle (even conveniently rearranging array `A`)?

Answer (score 4):

you can

```
n = numel(B);
iA = zeros( 1, n+1 ); %// +1 for boundary case
iA( A(:,1) ) = 1;
iA( A(:,2)+1 ) = -1;
iA(end) = []; %// discard boundary entry
B( cumsum(iA) > 0 ) = true;
```

Assumptions made

1. `A(:,1)` is always >= 1
2. `A(:,2)` is always <= `n` (number of elements in `B`)
3. the sections defined in `A` are non overlapping

Comment: if size of `B` is defined in terms of `A` you can set `n` to `n = max(A(:,2));`

Comment: It is not. Thanks for the suggestion, however I should define a further matrix that I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

If each stop is assured to be smaller than the next start (the index ranges don't overlap), another approach is

```
B(mod(sum(bsxfun(@le, 1:numel(B), [A(:,1)-1; A(:,2)])),2)>0) = true;
```

Comment: @Shai :-) But in this case it's probably very inefficient in terms of memory

Comment: @Shai Hahaha agreed. `bsxfun` is so much fun!

Comment: This seems to be a compact form of for cycle, right? Quite interesting, thanks

Comment: @RockeJoe Not just compact, but _vectorized_, that is, _fast_. (For comparison, `arrayfun` is a compact form of the `for` loop, but it's slow).